# Confused about PHP syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

I am following video tutorials on the Internet, and this is one of them. However, I am getting a syntax error and can't find where it is.

```
<?php

function hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih){
    $yil=$son-$ilk;
    $ay=$yil*12;
    $gun=$ay*30;
    return array("$ilktarih","$sontarih","$yil","$ay","$gun");
 }

 $ilktarih=$_POST["ilk"];
 $sontarih=$_POST["ikinci"];
 hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih);
 list ("$ilktarih","$sontarih",$yil,$ay,$gun)=hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih);

 ?>
```

Comment: I suspect it's the strings in `list` but would you mind telling us what the error actually *is*?

Comment: Maybe `$yil=$ilktarih-$sontarih` rather than those undefined vars `$son` and `$ilk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove double quotes from list variables like this :

```
 <?php
  function hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih){

    $yil=$son-$ilk;
   $ay=$yil*12;
    $gun=$ay*30;
    return array("$ilktarih","$sontarih","$yil","$ay","$gun");
 }
 $ilktarih=$_POST["ilk"];
 $sontarih=$_POST["ikinci"];
 hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih);
 list ($ilktarih,$sontarih,$yil,$ay,$gun)=hesapla($ilktarih,$sontarih);
?>
```